# Compression Task (Team Foundation Server)

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, compression, tfsbuild

I'm using Team Foundation Server, and I have to make a compressed zip file from my source code automatically everytime the build server builds the code.
This is a fragment of my project file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="Zipper" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Zipper" Condition="'$(ConfigTransform)'=='ImRunningOnTheServer'">
    <!-- I NEED A "COMPRESSION TASK" HERE-->
</Target>
```

Are there any compression task available? Maybe the desired task is defined in the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll assembly - but I don't know where it is. It is not available in the GAC, I think only on the build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Compression Tasks are part of the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/). I cannot find a link in the documentation at the moment (I think it's broken, or not IE9 compatible) to them, but they are there.

Comment: Thanks! It's inside the MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression namespace in the MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll assembly.